# Referencing item in ForLoop within Pandas column rename

Tags: python, pandas

I have two `pandas.DataFrame`'s and I wish to rename a column named `value`, which exists in both, as the name of the dataframe:

```
#Debt level relative to currency strength
#preamble
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.formula.api as sm #check that this is actually used
import os
import numpy as np

os.chdir('C:\\Users\\pineapple\\Desktop')

#function construction
def loader(y):
    return pd.read_csv(y, header='infer',  encoding="ISO-8859+-1")

def viewer(x):
    print(x.ix[:])

def delrow(x,y):
    return x[pd.notnull(x[y])]

#
names = ['currency', 'debt_ratio']

for i in names:
    i = loader(''+i+'.csv') #load data
    i = i.replace('..', np.NaN)

    for x in range(2007,2015):
        y = str(x)
        print(y)
        i=delrow(i, '' + y + ' [YR'+y+']') #deletes missing values
        i.rename(columns = {'' + y + ' [YR'+y+']': ''+ y +''}, inplace=True) #rename columns

    i = i.drop(['Series Name','Series Code', 'Country Name', \
         '1990 [YR1990]', '2000 [YR2000]' ], axis = 1)

    i = pd.melt(i, id_vars=['Country Code'],value_vars=['2007','2008','2009','2010','2011', \
    '2012','2013','2014']) #reshape

    i.rename(columns={'variable':'year', 'Country Code':'code'}, inplace=True)
    viewer(i)

    eval(i).rename(columns={'value':i}, inplace=True) #breaks here

    i['id'] = i['code'] + i['year']

    #output
    viewer(i)
```

This does not work - it fails to update the `value` column and messes up the format of the dataframe.

Comment: `i` is a string not a dataframe

Comment: change the first `i` in `i.rename` into your pandas `df`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change:

```
for i in names:
    i = loader(''+i+'.csv') #load data
```

To:

```
for name in names:
    i = loader(name + '.csv') #load data
```

Then do the rename with:

```
i.rename(columns={'value':name}, inplace=True)
```

Comment: This solved it. Scott Boston's answer works too but this fix was faster to implement. Thanks both.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `eval`:

## MCVE

```
a = pd.DataFrame({'Value':[1,2,3,4]})
b = pd.DataFrame({'Value':[5,6,7,9]})

names = ['a','b']

for i in names:
    eval(i).rename(columns={'Value':i}, inplace=True)

print(a)
```

Output:

```
   a
0  1
1  2
2  3
3  4

print(b)
```

Output:

```
   b
0  5
1  6
2  7
3  9
```

Comment: Thanks Scott - this does exactly what I want it to do; however when I add it into my code it returns the error: 'TypeError: eval() arg 1 must be a string, bytes or code object'. I've updated my original post so that it now shows all of the code; can you spot the error?

Comment: I must be a string not a variable to a dataframe.  Notice in my solution, I created a list of strings.  Then, I use eval to convert string into the variable for a dataframe. You are reassign i in your for loop to a bunch of things and when you finally call eval(i) it is no longer a string.